# вызвать функцию c# в javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Есть функция на c#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
     //функция
   }
}
```

нужно вызвать ее из клиентской стороны (примерно так)

```
<input id="Button" type="button" onserverclick="Button1_Click" value="Update"/>
```

естственно можно вызвать обычно:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**проблема в том что нельзя что бы происходил postback!**
Вопрос:как вызвать функцию с# из HTML/JavaScript без postback.
спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Click-эвенты (как и остальные эвенты в ASP.NET) требуют полного или частичного постбэка. Одна из причин этого - то, что состояние кнопки (видна она, не видна, существует ли вообще) хранится во ViewState - на клиентской стороне.

К тому же объект страницы на сервере существуюет только во время постбека. Без постбека ваш метод просто не у чего вызывать.

Возможн вам подойдет частичный постбек - просто оберните кнопку в `UpdatePanel`.

Или, если вам действительно надо просто вызвать метод - вы можете использовать Page Methods (правда, вам придется сделать метод статическим - т.к. экземпляр страницы без постбека на сервере не существует):

в aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMain" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    PageMethods.SomeMethod();
</script>
```

в codebehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void SomeMethod()
{

}
```

Comment: Справедливости ради - звать можно не обязательно функцию страницы, а например функцию из вебсервиса.

Comment: @cpp_user да, согласен. просто ответ-инструкция по написанию вебсервисов (с возможностью легко дернуть их из скрипта) будет чуть более объемной, и я не уверен что топикастер легко поймет в чем разница.

Comment: а как protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
     //функция
   }
}
переделать в
public static void SomeMethod()
{

}
?

Comment: @Dima заменить `protected` на `public`, добавить `static` убрать параметры (вы их скорее всего не используете. можно добавить любые параметры простых типов (int/string). имя функции можно оставить как есть.

Answer (score 1):

Установите себе Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX + AJAX Control Toolkit (optional).

Comment: Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX уже давным давно входит в сам .NET

Comment: Если автор откопал WebForms вместо MVC, то возможно у него еще не входит.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [AJAX](https://www.google.ru/search?q=asp.net%20webforms%20ajax). Больше и говорить нечего...